# How do I push a message from my Node application to the client for a single user (session)?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to push messages from the server to the client, instead of repeatedly pulling from the client side, so that each client receives messages just for that user. I'm using the Sails JS framework.

I have a `FooController` that fires events that the client is listening for. In that controller I have an action with the following:

```
var count = 0;
module.exports = {
    hello: function (req, res) {
        if (!req.isSocket) {
            return res.badRequest();
        }

        sails.sockets.join(req, 'someRoom', function(err) {
            console.log('joined');
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            console.log(req.cookies);
            sails.sockets.broadcast('someRoom', 'someEvent', { greeting: 'Hello. Counter is ' + (++count) });
        }, 500);

        res.json({status: 'Everything is okay'});
    }
};
```

Client side, I am listening for the event and make one request to it. This keeps firing the event on the server-side indefinitely because of the `setInterval`.

```
io.socket.on('someEvent', function (data){
  console.log('hello joined now');
  console.log(data);
});

console.log('making get request');
io.socket.get('/foo/hello', function (body, res) {
    console.log('server responded');
});
```

The problem is that when I make another request from a different browser, it seems that the counter variable is synced. For example, if I make a request from Chrome and let the counter count up to 100, then go to Firefox and navigate to the same page, the counter will return 101, 102, 103, etc in Firefox.

I'm wondering why the counter doesn't start back at 0 for the new session in Firefox?

Comment: Because ```count``` variable is on server side, not client side. So it will be synced.

Comment: @Bonanza Is there a way to start a new "instance" (might be the wrong word) of the backend controller when a different session tries to contact it?

Comment: If you want counter going from 0 from each user use either req.session.counter (will expire with session) or move it to client javascript (will expire with refreshing browser).